# Replacement for URI.escape that avoids Lint/UriEscapeUnescape warnings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, urlencode, lint, rubocop

Not sure how to fix **Rubocop's** [Lint/UriEscapeUnescape](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_lint/#linturiescapeunescape) warning

Tried replacing `URI` with `CGI` thinking that was the "drop in" replacement but that blew up the test suite.

Here's the error followed by the line of code where `URI` is being used:

```
app/models/media_file.rb:76:5: W: Lint/UriEscapeUnescape: URI.escape method is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, use CGI.escape, URI.encode_www_form or URI.encode_www_form_component depending on your specific use case.
    URI ...
    ^^^

    # app/models/media_file.rb
    ...
    def cdn_url(format: nil)
    if format.nil?
      "#{s3_config.cloudfront_endpoint}/#{escape_url(key)}"
    elsif converted_urls.with_indifferent_access[format.to_s]
      filename = converted_urls.with_indifferent_access[format.to_s]
      if URI.parse(escape_url(filename)).host
        filename
      else
        "#{s3_config.cloudfront_endpoint}/#{escape_url(filename)}"
      end
    else
      converted(url)
    end
  end
...
  private

  def escape_url(url)
    URI
      .escape(url)
      .gsub(/\(/, '%28')
      .gsub(/\)/, '%29')
      .gsub(/\[/, '%5B')
      .gsub(/\]/, '%5D')
  end
```

**EDIT:** Adding sample output of strings escaped with `URI` and `CGI`:

```
            url: images/medium/test-image.jpg
URI.escape(url): images/medium/test-image.jpg
CGI.escape(url): images%2Fmedium%2Ftest-image.jpg

            url: images/medium/test-image.jpg
URI.escape(url): images/medium/test-image.jpg
CGI.escape(url): images%2Fmedium%2Ftest-image.jpg
```

It would appear `CGI` is not a drop in replacement for `URI` as the listing error might have you believe. Thoughts?

Comment: Why do your tests fail? What URLs do you test, what output do you expect and what does it return instead?

Comment: The cop clearly tells you what to do. If `CGI.escape` causes errors, you need to fix those errors. We can't help you with that as you haven't included any inputs or the errors they're causing.

Comment: I added some output (above) so it's clear that the `URI.escape` and `CGI.escape` are doing different things… So, what is replacement if `URI.escape` is "obsolete"?

Comment: I recommend reading [the pull request that added it to rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/pull/4702). TLDR: `URI.escape` has been [deprecated in ruby trunk](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cd6df5fb3c1e9b965071d6a92ed1c7d4a938560f/lib/uri/common.rb#L80-L87) (and this is reflected [in the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html)), and the cop is warning you of that. Details of the alternate implementation are left to the reader, with `CGI` being given as one possible example.

Comment: `CGI.escape` is not a replacement for `URI.escape`. For example: `URI.escape('foo bar')` gives `'foo%20bar'`, while `CGI.escape('foo bar')` gives `'foo+bar'`. This causes problems if for example you are trying to escape a basic auth password that contains spaces. There are workarounds, but suggesting that OP just use `CGI.escape` when it's not the same thing is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Encounter with the same problem, got it fixed by using [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) lib.

```rb
escaped_query = URI.escape(search,
            Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))

#W: Lint/UriEscapeUnescape: URI.escape method is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, use CGI.escape, URI.encode_www_form or URI.encode_www_form_component depending on your specific use case.
```

Solved by:

- gem `addressable` gem in `gemspec` or `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'addressable', '~> 2.7'
```

- require `addressable/uri`
- Add appropriate.

```
escaped_query = Addressable::URI.encode_component(search, Addressable::URI::CharacterClasses::QUERY)
```